# Acumatica Vendor Export returning wrong data for Term, AP Account, and AP Sub

Tags: php, acumatica

I am using PHP to export Acumatica Vendor [AP30.30.00] data. I am getting the Vendor ID, and Vendor Name without an issue but when I try to get additional relational data; Term, AP Account, AP Sub, the data returned is not correct and repeated for all but the first vendor record returned.

Here is the code for creating the command.

```
$AP303000Content = $AP303000->GetSchemaResult;

$client->AP303000Clear();
// export 
$AP303000Export = new AP303000Export();
$AP303000Export->commands = array(
        $AP303000Content->VendorSummary->ServiceCommands->EveryVendorID,
        $AP303000Content->VendorSummary->VendorID,
        $AP303000Content->VendorSummary->VendorName,
        $AP303000Content->GeneralInfoFinancialSettings->Terms,
        $AP303000Content->GLAccountsAPAccount->APAccount,
        $AP303000Content->GLAccountsAPAccount->APSub
);
```

Any ideas why I am not getting the correct data for the last three fields?

Comment: What version of acumatica do you use?

Comment: For PHP experts, the issue seems to happen because of lack of Command type (SOAP request sent from PHP client contains no xsi:type="EveryValue":


-----SoapRequest at 8/12/2016 1:03:17 PM
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <AP303000Export xmlns="http://www.acumatica.com/generic/">
      <commands>
        <Command xsi:type="EveryValue">

Comment: Kirill, currently we are using 5.3

Comment: The code sample I provided results in <commands> <Command> ... does anyone have an PHP example on how to get the resulting request <commands> <Command xsi:type="EveryValue‌​">  as pointed out by Ruslan

Answer (score 0):

I landed here with the same wrong data issue; in my case, for the customer table.

I do not use php but Windows API; The helper is very similar.

This a simplified code for the everyvalue helper in Windows languaje:

```
   new Field
   {
   ObjectName = CustomerSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryCustomerID.ObjectName,
   FieldName = CustomerSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryCustomerID.FieldName,
   LinkedCommand.LinkedCommand <= CustomerSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryCustomerID.LinkedCommand.LinkedCommand,
   SOAPAddAttribute("xsi:type","EveryValue")
   },
```

I'd looped for every nested linkedcommand searching for a "xsi:type"="Key"; in the case o customer, the "Key" type was found in the second nested linkedcommand.

Francisco.